# How to convert Byte to UTF8?

Tags: hash

I'm using Buffer in js to convert a hex string to Bytes to UTF8:

```
const buf = Buffer.from("647c579f40734bd09b7bbb43b2092d84c820ff595f23ec04ce136851494cfe56", "hex");
const bufutf8 = buf.toString("utf-8");
```

Result:

> �\u0007\u001a\n���q\u001c<�G4]ø�a-\u0007\r�\n�ݿ�}`>��

And this utf8 only have 30 characters == 30 bytes which I cannot reverse back to original 32-byte hex with Buffer.from(utf8Str, "utf-8");

What am I missing here? Thx!

Comment: Aside from this question has no cryptographic component in it, conversion from and to any Unicode Transformation Format involve handling of illegal byte sequences, this handling will make the transformation between bytes and UTF non-bijective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, UTF-8 is a transformation format of Unicode, not of arbitrary byte string.

If you give an arbitrary byte string to a UTF-8 decoder, handling of invalid byte sequences will result in loss of information. This is the reason why your conversion is faulty.

Comment: I'll note that Base64 (and similar like Base65535) turns an arbitrary byte string into one which is valid UTF-8.